# Loading Hadoop-Azure in Kubernetes

Tags: azure, apache-spark

I am trying to get Apache Spark to load Hadoop-Azure when running using the new Kubernetes feature.

No matter my efforts, Apache Spark always gives me the following error **java.lang.classnotfoundexception: Class org.apache.hadoop.fs.azure.NativeAzureFileSystem not found** when trying to load a file using the **wabs://** schema

My dockerfile right now

```
FROM spark:latest

COPY *.jar $SPARK_HOME/jars

ENV SPARK_EXTRA_CLASSPATH="$SPARK_HOME/jars/hadoop-azure-3.2.0.jar:$SPARK_HOME/jars/azure-keyvault-core-1.2.4.jar:$SPARK_HOME/jars/azure-storage-8.6.6.jar:$SPARK_HOME/jars/azure-storage-8.6.6.jar:$SPARK_HOME/jars/jetty-util-ajax-9.3.24.v20180605.jar:$SPARK_HOME/jars/wildfly-openssl-2.1.3.Final.jar"
ENV HADOOP_OPTIONAL_TOOLS="hadoop-azure,hadoop-azure-datalake"
```

*(spark:latest is a build of kubernetes\dockerfiles\spark\Dockerfile from spark-3.1.1-bin-hadoop3.2)*

The directory contains the following jars:

- hadoop-azure-3.2.0.jar
- azure-storage-8.6.6.jar
- azure-keyvault-core-1.2.4.jar
- jetty-util-ajax-9.3.24.v20180605.jar
- wildfly-openssl-2.1.3.Final.jar

I have validated that the files are copied and stored in /opt/spark/jars

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I needed to-do two things before this worked.

Number one was getting the correct dependencies installed. I did this by creating a new pom.xml with the following dependencies

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
    <artifactId>hadoop-azure</artifactId>
    <version>3.2.2</version>
</dependency>
```

And then running `mvn install dependency:copy-dependencies`. I could then copy the output jars files to the directory that contains my `Dockerfile` and create a simple Dockerfile with this content:

```
FROM spark:latest
USER root
COPY ./*.jar $SPARK_HOME/jars
RUN chmod -R 775 $SPARK_HOME/jars
USER 185
```

However I had another issue as well. I was trying to use `wabs://` when running in Client Mode. If your running in Client Mode, the jars also have to be copied to `/opt/spark/jars` on the machine creating the SparkContext.

Answer (score 0):

This code works for me:

```
ENV \
    AZURE_STORAGE_VER=8.6.6 \
    HADOOP_AZURE_VER=3.3.0 \
    JETTY_VER=9.4.38.v20210224

# Set JARS env
ENV JARS=${SPARK_HOME}/jars/azure-storage-${AZURE_STORAGE_VER}.jar,${SPARK_HOME}/jars/hadoop-azure-${HADOOP_AZURE_VER}.jar,${SPARK_HOME}/jars/jetty-util-ajax-${JETTY_VER}.jar,${SPARK_HOME}/jars/jetty-util-${JETTY_VER}.jar

RUN echo "spark.jars ${JARS}" >> $SPARK_HOME/conf/spark-defaults.conf
```

But you will need to add this jar as well: `jetty-util-9.4.38.v20210224.jar`

Comment: Any chance you can share the rest of your Dockerfile? Or just the versions your using together with what version of Spark?

Comment: Please see above, I have added the versions that work.

Comment: Thanks for the help Frank, you pointed my in the right direction, but I ended up with a more convoluted solutions.